# Different chrome FPS meters

Tags: google-chrome, electron

I've been developing on chrome Version 84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit) and have recently moved the app into electron.

As a result the internal FPS meter has changed to a much less readable version (the top one of the image) from the standard (bottom one) I've been used to. Is there an option or technique to swap it back as I find the new electron one very difficult to use as the text is so overlapped.

[image]